# Creating 1000 digit within 10 loops only

Tags: php, loops

Is it possible to create 1000 numbers from 0000 to 9999 using only 10 loops?

```html
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) 
{ 
 # code...
    $numberList .= ""; 
}
                   
echo $numberList;
                   
result: 0000, 0001, 0002, ... 9999
```

UPDATES

I need to minimize the code because I have a not so good server.
I am working on huge list of numbers.
Example: 1000-1999, 2000-2999, ... 9000-9999

and also xxx-1000 to xxx-19999, xxx-2000 to xxx-2999, ... xxx-9000 to xxx-9999

Comment: You can even create without loops, are you interested?

Comment: This sounds a lot like an assignment question.

Comment: @Thamilan I need to create code because on actual application in should be from 1000-1999 and 2000-2999 ... 9000-9999

Comment: Hint 10 loops X 100 == 1000. But look at `range()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it helpful to do it like this?

```
$numberList = array();
for($i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for($j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        for($k = 0; k < 10; k++){
            for($l = 0; l < 10; l++){
                $numberList[] = i . j . k . l;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you will have all 4 digits even the most significant zeros like '0001'.